# How to highlight active tab in tabmenu in typescript

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I am using a js tabs menu in angular using typescript and component but i am not able to add the functionality to highlight the active tab by changing its background color

**TABMENU CODE IN COMPONENT.HTML**

```
<div class="tabnav">
        <button class="buttontab left" (click)="openTab('direct')" >Direct Receipt</button>
        <button class="buttontab right" (click)="openTab('sto')" >STO Receipt</button>
</div>
```

**JS FUNCTION IN COMPONENT.TS**

```
 openTab(tab) : void {
    var tabname = tab;
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("content");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      (<any>x[i]).style.display = "none"; 
    }
    document.getElementById(tabname).style.display = "block";   
  }
```

Comment: How do you want to highlight it ? By changing background color, by adding a shadow, by adding a zoom out effect ?

Comment: by changing the background color

Answer (score 1):

It could be done like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  template: `
    <div class="tabnav">
      <button [ngClass]="{ active: isActive(1) }" (click)="openTab(1)">
        Direct Receipt
      </button>
      <button [ngClass]="{ active: isActive(2) }" (click)="openTab(2)">
        STO Receipt
      </button>

      <div [hidden]="!isActive(1)">
        <h4>Direct Receipt Content</h4>
      </div>
      <div [hidden]="!isActive(2)">
        <h4>STO Receipt Content</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
      .active {
        border-color: blue;
      }
    `
  ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular";
  tab = 1;

  isActive(tabId): boolean {
    return this.tab === tabId;
  }

  openTab(tabId): void {
    this.tab = tabId;
  }
}
```

[Online Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b8ec7x)

Comment: @AayushGupta As can be seen in the demo, it works properly. Do you have any error?

Comment: i am not to able to merge this part of yours into my code. If possible can you reply me the whole function of openTab

Comment: @AayushGupta I did it by CSS instead of style. I think you didn't see `app.component.css` in the online demo. Please see it again.

Comment: I don't know what is `var x = document.getElementsByClassName("content");` to help you better, but you can do everything that you like in `openTab`.

Comment: this var x is the variable which is storing my content div. the content is switching when the tabs switch

Comment: @AayushGupta I got it. I have changed my code and the demo to cover the content. See it again.

Comment: its working but by default both tabs content are opening

Comment: @AayushGupta to fix it, default tab id (`tab = 1;`) should be set.